# lightning:unsavedChanges not works with console application

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforce-id, simple-salesforce

lightning:unsavedChanges not works while doing tab switch in console application.

It works fine on tab switching in standard application.
Any thoughts?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that tab switching in the standard application causes the current page to change, triggering unsavedChanges to fire. Tab switching in the console keeps the current page up, while changing to another tab. Thus it doesn't warn the user.

Comment: Yeah..I also have same assumption